# Making wget's --convert-links respect http vs https

Tags: wget, https

I'm using the following command to mirror an https website:

```
wget --directory-prefix=/tmp/mirror --mirror --no-host-directories \
     --regex-type pcre --reject-regex "$SKIP_REGEXP" \
     --convert-links --adjust-extension --header "Accept-Language: en-US,en" \
     --header "X-Build-Mirror: True" -o /tmp/mirror.log https://logic.ff.cuni.cz
```

(Actually, the command runs as a single line - I've broken it over several lines for improved readability.)

Per the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html#Recursive-Retrieval-Options) of the `--convert-links` flag, links to downloaded files are converted to relative links for local viewing and links to files which are not downloaded (e.g. because of `--reject-regexp`) are converted to absolute links. However, in the conversion, although the host url is an *https* url, all absolute links become *http* links!!

Is this a bug in `wget` or is there some way to force it to respect the protocol type? (I know that I can use the `--https-only` [flag](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options.html#HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options), but that would prevent getting **any** http resource.)

Comment: This is almost definitely a bug in Wget. I'll open a bug-report on your behalf.